# new to ios - not sure how property is being used

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been going through the [following tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial) and came across this line which I dont understand how it works:

```
NSArray *upcomingWeather = [self.weather upcomingWeather];
```

I have tried to understand how this works, and spent long hours. here is what i know.  upcomingWeather is a method which extracts a json portion and returns it into an array. However, i have no idea what purpose this is for: self.weather <-- no clue how that is being used. Can you explain the significance of self.weather ?

Comment: btw, I am new to iOS, this may be a basic question

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.weather upcomingWeather];
```

There are no functions in Objective-c, there are messages. `self.weather` is an object to which you send message `upcomingWeather`. These messages are something similar to function with one big difference : if the object is nil, exception is silenced and you will get no error when sending message.

Furthermore, in any given case first part in [%@ %@] is an object, and the second one is the message you are sending. In case you have more then one parameter you will use it as :

```
[self.weather upcomingWeather:parameterOne andWithParameterTwo:parameterTwo];
```

The important thing to mention here is that, when declaring funtions, you have two parts : private and public. You send message with accessing public part and use private part in the function. To better understand this take a look at the example:

```
-(void) test:(NSString*)PO andWithParameterTwo(NSString*)PW{}
```

`PO` and `PW` is private parts -  you use them in method, while `andWithParametersTwo` is public part and you access them when you send that message.

Edit:

> “Wait a minute!”, you might be thinking. What is this [self.weather
>   upcomingWeather]? If self.weather is a plain old NSDictionary, how
>   does it know what “upcomingWeather” is? To make it easier to display
>   the data, I added a couple of helper categories on NSDictionary in the
>   starter project: NSDictionary+weather NSDictionary+weather_package
>   These categories add some handy methods that make it a little easier
>   to access the data elements. You want to focus on the networking part
>   and not on navigating NSDictionary keys, right?

You are right, `self.weather` is dictionary, but this guy created helper categories, so NSDictionary is extended(among others) with this method:

```
- (NSArray *)upcomingWeather
{
    NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
    return dict[@"weather"];
}
```

So when you send `upcomingWeather` message, this method will be called.

Comment: thats really confusing, can you further explain it to me? from what i understand, self.weather is a dictionary which hold values... right ?

Comment: sorry about the delay, question i have still- self.weather is a dictionary, i dont understand what it's purpose here is for ?

Comment: Yeah, it is. This guy created some kind of helper function for dictionary - you can call this function on ANY NSDictionary, but if there is no @"data" key it will be nil. This will only return Array for the key inside dictionary. It is basicly the same thing as :
[[self.weather objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"weather"]